# IDA how to view path between 2 functions

Tags: ida

I like to view the path between 2 functions with IDA 7.0.

I have already tried with "function browser" but not work becouse these 2 functions are not linked.

For what I see there is no way to choose multiple functions and see their position in the graph.

There is a way with IDA or other software to show the path between multiple functions ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit complicated but should be possible via the [proximity view](https://www.hex-rays.com/blog/new-feature-in-ida-6-2-the-proximity-browser/). You can also try a third party plugin [AlleyCat](https://github.com/tacnetsol/ida/tree/master/plugins/alleycat).

Answer (score 0):

Go to the function you know or assume to be higher on the call stack, select the function name and press `X` or right-click->`'Jump to xref...'` for a list of **direct** references. To look for a given function, do that recursively for all the references from the list. A more time-saving method though would be setting two breakpoints in a debugger and logging all the in-between callers.

Comment: thank you, but in this way I can't see the path of my 2 functions. For what I known IDA don't allow to show the path of  x selected functions. But exist some old python plug-in that allow it, but I never used it and I don't known how install it.